# Why is the gradient defined as a vector function and not as a vector?

Tags: vector-analysis

According to [this](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/grad/grad.html) article:

The gradient of a function w=f(x,y,z) is the vector function:

$<\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, y, z), \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, y, y),\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} (x, y, z)>$

Isn't this a vector? Why do we call it a function?

Comment: The gradient is dependent on the function. Hence, it's not a vector, but its a function that outputs a vector.

Comment: @RushabhMehta That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because it depends on $(x,y,z)$.

(Such a function, which assigns a vector to each point $(x,y,z)$, is also called a vector *field*.)